# Synchronous External Abort on ARM

Tags: exception, arm, abort

I was building a bare metal application on ARM Cortex A9 Pandaboard, and I got Instruction Fetch Abort frequently. When I dump IFSR Register I got 0x1008. I've read the reference manual, and I understand that 1008 was Synchronous External Abort. The problem is what synchronous external abort means and where does it come from? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [ARMv7 ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0406c/index.html) section "VMSA Memory aborts" covers this as thoroughly as one would expect (given that it's the authoritative definition of the architecture), but to summarise in slightly less than 14 pages;

An **abort** means the CPU tried to make a memory access, which for whatever reason, couldn't be completed so raises an exception.

An **external** abort is one from, well, externally to the processor, i.e. something on the bus. In other words, the access didn't fault in the MMU, went out onto the bus, and either some device or the interconnect itself came back and said "hey, I can't deal with this".

A **synchronous** external abort means you're rather fortunate, in that it's not going to be utterly hideous to debug - in the case of a prefetch abort, it means the `IFAR` is going to contain a valid VA for the faulting instruction, so you know exactly what caused it. The unpleasant alternative is an *asynchronous* external abort, which is little more than an interrupt to say "hey, something you did a while ago didn't actually work. No I don't know what is was either."

So, you're trying to execute instructions from something that you *think* is memory, but isn't. Without any further details, the actual cause could be anything from a typoed hard-coded address, to dodgy page tables, stale TLB entries, cache coherency, etc. etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I got clear understanding about my problem. But in few minutes ago I tried to insert a functions for flushing my cache and those aborts never happened. Is there any problem with the cache? I used shared normal memory attributes in my translation table to use the cache.

Comment: Do you have the right attributes set in the relevant `TTBRn` for coherent table walks? Remember the attributes in the table entries themselves only affect CPU accesses translated by the MMU - the MMU table walker is a separate interface.

Comment: I was using short descriptor format for my 32 bit ARM boards. I've set Shareable bit in TTBR0 register through CP15 access. But when I tried to set L1 Prefetch bit and inner cacheablity (IRGN) attribute, I got a strange behaviour. I coudn't set those two bits, and my TTBR0 always had only Shareable bit set. Did I missed something important?